# Why does this generate an Infinite Loop?

Tags: c, loops, file-io, infinite-loop

Here is the portion of my C program:

```
FILE *fin_length;
int c;
int countNewLines = 0;

fin_length = fopen( argv[1], "r" );

while( ( c == fgetc( fin_length ) ) != EOF ) {

    if( c == 10 ) countNewLines++;
}

fclose( fin_length );
```

I run the program with command line arguments `./a.out myMessage.dat`.  `myMessage.dat` is 5 lines long, where each line contains nothing more than a short sentence.  Therefore, I expect the loop to find these 5 lines with `if( c == 10 )` and add one to `countNewLines` every time it finds a carriage return.

Why am I getting an infinite loop here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`while( ( c == fgetc( fin_length ) ) != EOF ) {`

You have too many equal signs. This should be

`while( ( c = fgetc( fin_length ) ) != EOF ) {`

When you use `==`, you end up with two comparisons. The first is a comparison between `c` and the return value of `fgetc()`.

The second comparison compares that result (which is either `true` or `false`) with `EOF`.  I have not looked up the value of `EOF`, but it is certainly not `0` or `1` - meaning that the second comparison will never return false.

Comment: AFAIK, `EOF` is normally `-1`, to ensure that it is not equal to any `int` value that is a valid `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 4):

Because you used `==` in your while, you want this:

```
while ((c = fgetc(fin_length)) != EOF) {
```

You were getting a boolean from `==` then comparing that against `EOF`, and it was never equal, so your loop was infinite.

Answer (score 2):

Because `==` (equality) is not the same as `=` (assignment).

Happy coding.

Comment: Aha.  I put `==` because I thought to myself "I'm testing conditions in a while loop, so I should use that", however I now realize that in this case, I'm assigning a value to `c`, **then** using `!=` to compare it to `EOF`.  Thank you very much!

Comment: @Mike Gates You're welcome :-) I would enable all warnings (-Wall in GCC), although I don't think it'd warn in this case because of the parenthesis.

Comment: My professor requires a GCC with -ansi, -pedantic, AND -Wall.  There was no error stated when I did that though.